# Custom membership provider from MYSQL Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am implementing my custom membership provider  for MYSQL for this I write this code:

```
public class CustomSqlMembershipProvider : MySQLMembershipProvider
{  
  public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection configs)
  {
    base.Initialize(name, configs);
  }
}
```

When  I am compiling this class, getting an error:

```
'Project.Models.CustomSqlMembershipProvider': cannot derive from sealed type
'MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider' C:\...\CustomSqlMembershipProvider.cs
```

Why I getting this error? I have added the MySql.web and MySql.Data assembly references.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inherit from a [`sealed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw(VS.71).aspx) class.
You *can* however write your own custom MySql membership provider by inheriting from [`MembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx)

Comment: I only want to write the code to set connection string  from external file and, I want to use inbuilt code from membership provider.

Comment: please give the suggestion what to do, how to do

Comment: @Aayushi the only way you can set the connectionstring is the method described here: http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/02/how-to-setup-and-configure-mysql-membership-provider-6-2-2-porting-to-mono-part-2-of-3/

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat off point, but after spending more time than I care to think about wrestling with creating custom MembershipProviders it suddenly occurred to me that other than losing the ability to use Microsoft's provided tools for managing users and roles, jettisoning MembershipProvider, RoleProvider and the like isn't that big a deal. At least, it isn't if you're using something like EntityFramework or, better yet, nHydrate, to handle the CRUDdy details of database interaction.

Put another way, since I'm using a framework (nHydrate) anyway, I'm finding it easier to set up my own custom authentication protocols. For example, I keep what Microsoft considers "user profile" information in the same table as I do the authentication credential information. For me, that's a much more natural approach for many projects.

Your mileage may vary, of course.

Answer (score 0):

As Klaus says you cannot subclass a class marked "sealed". You could however do one of these alternatives:

1. If you have the connector source code remove the "sealed" keyword. dirty i know...
2. The better alternative would be to use the "adapter" pattern (sources below example)

adapter:

```
public class MyMySqlProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    private MySQLMembershipProvider mySqlImpl = new MySQLMembershipProvider();

    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection configs) 
    {
        mySqlImpl.Initialize(name, configs);
        base.Initialie(name, configs);
    }

    public override bool OverrideSomethingElse()
    {
        bool someBool = mySqlImpl.OverrideSomethingElse();

        if (someBool)
        {
            //someBool = adapt to something else;
        }

        return someBool;
    }
}
```

The idea is to implement the common methods between the two to "adapt" to your interface.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern